# How to reset the entire page and results table when we change tabs in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

This error is occurring,

For example, please imagine this instance, if we got two tabs (A and B) with an input field, and if we type something in tab A and click on submit, a table will appear with values, then if I suddenly move to tab B, the input field has the same value whatever I entered in tab A, and also the same table is listing.

For the input field, I used useEffect for every tab change the input value should be empty like this,

```
    useEffect(() => {
       setInputfield("")
},[props.tabChange])
```

and it works fine, but

> the table keeps showing, I also want the table to get hidden when the tab changes.

And I am actually using like this,

```
<Route  path ={tabPath} render{() => <Tab tabType={"A"}/>}
<Route  path ={tabPath} render{() => <Tab tabType={"B"}/>}
```

Could someone please help me, it would be highly appreciable!

Comment: You have to unmount the component, then after you leave it and try to mount it again you are going to have a fresh component without any data.

Comment: @EmadBaqeri I am sorry I am new to the react, could you please tell me how to do them unmount in the sense of what needs to be done?

Comment: Do not be sorry my friend, welcome to the community of react ;)
I imagine you are learning react in functional component paradigm, [this link](https://dev.to/robmarshall/how-to-use-componentwillunmount-with-functional-components-in-react-2a5g) might help you.

Comment: @EmadBaqeri, thanks mate, I will give it a look at this document.

Comment: use hook called useRef to create input element reference ex: username and in useEffect(()=>{ return ()=>{ username.target.value = ''  },[]}

Comment: @BalagoniHarish, but for the table what should I do? because once I click on submit in tab A it displays the table, and if I migrate to tab B, the table still displays.

Comment: Take it easy my friend.
You can switch it off and on with a simple `const [showTable, setShowTable] = React.useState<boolean>(false); ` if the `showTable` is true you can see the table.

Comment: And do not forget to try things on your own ;)